# Unable to join to domain hosted on Azure VM

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-vpn

So I've created a VM Win Server 2016 on Azure. I've created a VPN connection between Azure VM (Which is AD DC) and a test windows machine. I can ping AD IP (but not domain, only IP), RDP into machine etc.. however when I try to join domain it's not recognized. So it's probably DNS issue on Azure but I've been unable to resolve it? What to do? How to proceed? The idea is to be able to connect remote machines via Point to Site VPN to AD DC on Azure.
Thanks

Comment: sorry, didnt read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your DC listed as a DNS server if you are doing AD integrated DNS Or have a public record so that the Azure DNS servers can advertise it. Make sure you have done the step - [Reset the DNS server for the Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine#reset-the-dns-server-for-the-azure-virtual-network). You can also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156090.aspx for guidance and http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-install-replica-active-directory-domain-controller/ for steps.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a VPN connection between Azure VM (Which is AD DC) and a
>   test windows machine.

Could you please tell me which kind VPN do you deployed?

If you select **S2S VPN**, we can change the test windows machine's DNS to Azure VM's **private IP address**, then try to ping the domain name, if we can ping it, we can join this test vm to the AD DC.

If your VPN is **P2S**, we should change the test windows machine's DNS to the Azure VM **P2S virtual IP address**(get from p2s), then try to ping the domain name, and join to it.

Comment: Can you join to a domain now? please let me know if you need more help:)